# Setting Form bounds exactly when shadow is displayed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm stuck trying to display a form matching a certain rectangle if the form has the slight shadow effect of windows 10 - instead of the form itself, setting the Bounds seems to set the size including the shadow so the form is smaller than the rectangle:

[image]

What I tried:

- setting DWMNCRP_DISABLED when I set the Form bounds and turning that back afterwards
- switching off the CS_DROPSHADOW flag (for good measure, shouldn't apply here)
- setting ClientSize after setting the bounds - not good as that means it will be offset from the right corner pos, and I'm not sure how to get the size of the shadow

Only windows 7 throught to windows 10 support is needed.

Comment: Can you provide some code on what you are trying to do?  It's not exactly clear.  Are you trying to line up two forms next to each other, etc?

Comment: Bounds includes the window borders, used to be 2 pixels wide.  Lasted for 20 years but it became too hard to hit with a mouse.  Vista was the first OS to virtualize the border, making it intentionally wider beyond the programmer's request.  Big changes again at Win10, default DPI not 96 anymore, the border is now transparent and the mouse is active in the shadow.  There is no api to find the actual border width, that was intentional.  If you want precision for every OS and every DPI selection then use a borderless window.

Comment: @HansPassant the thing is, I want the window to be resizeable afterwards. If I set the border style to None and set the bounds, it fits perfectly, yes, but when I set the border style back, I get the same shifted result as when setting ClientSize after setting the bounds...

Comment: Hmya, it isn't shifted.  It merely looks like it is, that transparent border really is there, you just can't see it.   Not hard to notice however when you hover the mouse on it, like your user will do when trying to resize the window.  There are many existing Q+A at SO that tell you how to provide resizing support for a borderless window.

Comment: Yeah, I mean shifted from the viewpoint of the user - it's not a usable area, just a resize border. Also, for the resizing solution, I wouldn't be able to use the full area of the form anymore since I'd have to set some space aside for the border (and preferably variable amount depending on the DPI used). Asked the question because I thought I'm missing something obvious. For now, I'll expand the window by the difference of Size and ClientSize and shift the Location by half the amount then...